# Scrape data from a public API politely using postman?

Tags: postman

I'm trying to scrape data from a public API and I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this the right way.

The API is RESTful and I'm looking to:

- Grab the first 100 results
- Save the JSON result to a unique filename
- Wait the required amount of time (15 seconds) to not violate usage guidelines
- Set the offset += 100
- Grab the next 100
- Either save the JSON results as a new unique filename or even append results to the previous one
- Continue until response != 200 or I get 0 results back

Is Postman even the right tool to use for this?  I'm not very familiar with scripting in Postman.

`{{URL}}/v1/titles?api_key=123456&limit=100&offset=0`

Comment: Can you show example which public API? Also, it seems like out of scope Postman feature. It needs to develop by programming language like node.js.